# FFMPEG - Difference between "-ab" and "-b:a"

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, bitrate

As far as i know both Commandline Args change the Audio Bitrate, but ime not exactly sure because i have also seen them in combination. 
Basically i couldn't find any Documentation that explains both of these Commands. It could also be that -ab got replaced with -b:a but ime not exactly sure.

TY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. `-ab` is the legacy option name and is an alias for `-b:a`.